# Where do I find the settings and administration menu?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, unity

In Ubuntu Unity, I can't seem to find the settings and administration menus, are they anywhere to be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have all your System and Administration applications on "Applications" icon on the Dock. You click on it and then select "System". It will show you your most used Apps, and under them all you your System and Admin apps.

Comment: Yes, I've found that, but it seems that not all the entries I'd usually find in the settings and administration menus is there...

Comment: Well, this is because they are a bit minimized (I think, I do not use Unity). Try to execute "alacarte" on Terminal. And enable or disable the àpps you want to see in every section of applications.

Comment: Yes, there I can move elements from the System menus to the applications menu. That solves the problem.